# How to turn this into an algorithm? my code detects split cell lines and joins them together but is limited to three cases

Tags: c#, csv

Overview: I am trying to detect a split line and then join it together. A split line can be detected by checking if it starts with: " but does not end with a quote. The below code works, however it only works with three cases.

How to turn this into an algorithm?

Csv file:

```
ColumnOne             | ColumnTwo
-----------------------------------
"this is same         | good

 line"
```

Main Method:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> list = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("MyCsvFile.csv", Encoding.Default));

        JoinSplitCellLines();
        File.WriteAllLines("results.csv",list);
    }
```

Worker Method:

```
    public void JoinSplitCellLines()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (!list[i].EndsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // three split lines
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list[i + 2]))
                    {
                        list[i] = list[i] + list[i + 3];
                        list.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                        list.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                        list.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    }
                    // two split lines
                    else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list[i + 1]))
                    {
                        list[i] = list[i] + list[i + 2];
                        list.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                        list.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    }
                    // one split line
                    else
                    {
                        list[i] = list[i] + list[i + 1];
                        list.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote code which should work universally but it is hard to check if there are no mistakes without an example input. You can use it is as a guideline:

```
public void JoinSplitCellLines()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!list[i].EndsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                for (var j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list[j]))
                    {
                        list[i] = list[i] + list[j + 1];
                        list.RemoveRange(i, j - i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a clear direction, made a small adjustment and it works great

Answer (score 0):

```
public void JoinSplitCellLines()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if(list[i].StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && 
           !list[i].EndsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)){
            while(!list[i+1].EndsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)){
                    list.RemoveAt(i+1);
            }
            list[i]+=list[i+1];
            list.RemoveAt(i+1);
        }
     }
}
```

In theory this will iterate over your list, check if there is an "open-ended" string in the current line, remove all empty lines inbetween, and add the next line that ends with double quotes before removing that too.

I'm vague about my answer as I don't see why your multiline strings are always two actual lines and an unknown number of empty lines inbetween and no string with three lines of actual text for example.

Notice: the `while` may run into errors if your csv file ends with an open string. It tries to access and remove list entries until it finds a double quote.

Notice 2: I wonder how your code is supposed to work as you define your list as a local variable not an attribute but don't pass it as a parameter to your method either. As of now, there is no list that `JoinSplitCellLines()` can process. I did not include such a fix in my code either.

*Correct me if I did understand your code wrong or if you ran into errors with my code, I didn't test it.*